# WPF Equivalent of OwnerDraw

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, ownerdrawn

In a WinForms application that I currently maintain I have a tree control with several thousand nodes in it.  Each node is owner drawn with a custom, dynamically generated, icon (each icon is unique).  I'm thinking about converting this application in to WPF, but I don't know how to properly handle this tree view.  I know the standard way of doing this in WPF would be to use a template for each item with an image control for my icon content, but I'm worried about performance if I bind several thousand dynamically created images.  With OwnerDraw I don't have to store the icon, I can just generate and paint it only when the nodes are actual visible.

Is there a standard way of handling this scenario in WPF?

Screenshots of the current application can be seen [here](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=103360.0) to give you an idea of what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

A correct tree implementation will always virtualize its items, meaning only those currently displayed will be bound to data and rendered. Knowing this, simply generate your image dynamically when it's needed.

View side, item template:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
<DataTemplate>
```

Model side :

```
private ImageSource _image;

public ImageSource Image {
  get { return _image ?? (_image = CreateImage()); }
}

private ImageSource CreateImage() {
   // load your image dynamically here
   // If you're creating it from scratch, WriteableBitmap might help you
}
```

This code caches the image into the `_image` field. If you don't need it, you can simply re-create it each time `Image` is accessed (be careful not to access the property too often).